# How do I capture integers from a string in C#?

Tags: c#

In this project I need to separate the Booking ID from the string below into a separate integer.

```
Booking ID: 27620
Booked for Paitient(ID): 003
Booked Staff ID: 001
Booked Room: b001
Booked Equipment: Adam
```

How do I do this in C#?

To clarify: The code above is the whole string, the first line is where the booking ID is contained. I need help finding a way to separate the ID from the string. 
I have tried Regex but to no prevail. I cannot get my head around the string formatting. 
The ID can be any length.

Comment: Do you have some code (an attempt) you can show us?

Comment: `(?<notInteger>\D+)(?<integer>\d+)`

Comment: I doubt someone will write the solution for you. But read about Regular Expressions and `Regex` class, then show what have you done so far.

Comment: Why don't you just make a class that holds this data separately? For example: create a class called Booking and add properties to it. (Id, Patient, StaffId, Room, Equipment) That way you can easily get the data you want

Comment: @Dries: think for a second that the data is coming from 3rd party data source

Comment: @KonradKokosa LOL.. there is always someone. :)

Comment: I had a few attempts at it, however I ended up deleting them because they dint work as intended. I dabbled in Regex, however I couldn't get my head around the string formats. And to clear up the booking ID can be any length. And it is all one string

Comment: Hmm yeah, should've thought some more before commenting. Allthough it would be good to capture this string and put in a class if he/she were to use this data multiple times

Comment: Assuming you had a string called `myString` you could split it out like this.  

    string myString = "Booking ID: 27620";
    var myInt = int.Parse(myString.Split(':')[1]);

This likely won't work in your scenario perfectly, so you will still nede to tweak this for your exact requirements.

Comment: @Vijay Yes that would be a way to do it, i'll give it a go now. Thanks

Comment: @AdamMeadows, regex is simple and only captures the digits, not extra spaces that you need to trim.  My answer should cover that.

Comment: Did my answer get posted before the question was put on hold?  I see it, but do you?

Comment: @paqogomez Yes I just replied. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex can handle what you are looking for.

```
string text = "Booking ID: 27620 ..."; 
foreach (string line in new LineReader(() => new StringReader(text))
{
    string result = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^\d]", "");
    Console.WriteLine(result); // >> 27620
}
```

The regex `"[^\d]"` says:

`[]` Capture

`^\d` Everything that is not (`^`) a digit (`\d`)

Then the `Replace` replaces it all with an empty string.

This would be most valuble if you were looping through each line of your file.

If you needed to keep the field value, then running a simple split would be the better way to go.

```
string input = "Booking ID: 27620";
Dictionary<string, string> dict = 
    new Dictionary<string, string>{key = input.Split(':')[0], 
                                 value = input.Split(':')[1]};
```

Comment: This seperates all the int's from the whole string. I only need the BookingID. Also can you explain (Or link) to understanding the string formats. Thank you

Comment: You'd probably want to implement this in a loop, where you look at each line of your file.  I'll break down the regex in an edit.

Comment: Perfect, with a bit of messing around I got it to work. Thank you!

Comment: @AdamMeadows i added a string line reader in there so it would loop for you.  You dont show how you are getting this out, so this is probably inefficient, but if you dont want to monkey w/ how you are creating the string, that would work.  Dont forget to mark as answer and upvote! good luck!